# Dump integer-only sql table to binary file?

Tags: postgresql, binary, pg-dump

I have a PostgrqSQL table w/ a bunch of columns that are just different sizes of integer.

```
              Table "public.place2022_final"
    Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 toff          | integer |           |          | 
 palette_index | bigint  |           |          | 
 censorship    | boolean |           |          | 
 row0          | integer |           |          | 
 col0          | integer |           |          | 
 row1          | integer |           |          | 
 col1          | integer |           |          | 
 uint_id       | bigint  |           |          | 
 seqno         | bigint  |           |          |
```

I can export it to a CSV, but for my purposes I really want the data to be small. Is there a way I  can create a minimal dump to a binary file, w/ a format something like

```
<8 bytes for # of rows in table><4 bytes for row 1 toff><8 bytes for row 1 palette_index>...<do that for all fields, then repeat for all rows>.
```

I also know for a fact that all these bigints can be squashed down to 32-bit ints... so doing that "conversion" here would be nice too.

Comment: You will need to write a program for that. SQL or the Postgres provided tools can't do that. CSV is a text format to begin with, so it isn't capable of storing "binary integers" at all.

Comment: Yes, I was just saying that I knew how to go from db -> csv. My question was if there was a db -> binary operation, not a csv -> binary one. Regardless, you seem to have answered it

Comment: From here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html); `pg_dump -Fc -t place2022_final -a -f place2022_final_data.out`. This will a compressed(the -Fc)  file of just the data from the table. It will actually be a `COPY` of the data. You can then use [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) to either restore to the table or to a file as a text version.

Comment: FYI, the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command does have a binary format. I have never used it so I can't comment on its effectiveness.  At the provided link search for *Binary Format* to get the details.